# LSTM validation accuracy fluctuating

Tags: validation, lstm

I am using LSTM to model time series data. My target variable is categorical so I am using one-hot encoding. The goal is to predict the target class based on the given time. My dataset spans over eight days.

```
   input_nodes = look_back = 10
   batch_size = 128
   train_generator = create_data_generator(train, look_back, outputs, batch_size, class_weights_dict)
   validation_generator = create_test_generator(test, look_back, outputs, batch_size)

   model = Sequential()
   model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(input_nodes, outputs)))
   #model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(outputs, activation='softmax'))
   model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

   # fit network
   history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                                 steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(len(train)/batch_size),
                                 epochs=25,
                                 validation_data=validation_generator,
                                 validation_steps=math.ceil(len(test)/batch_size))
```

Here are my results.

[image]

[image]

Is there anything that I can try to improve my validation accuracy and loss?

Comment: Since you're using one-hot encoding of the categories, then the categories must be mutually exclusive. Why are you using sigmoid instead of softmax as the output activation? Do you have 3 or more categories?

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood then. I will switch back to `softwax`. The fluctuations are still there and the validation accuracy is till around 50%.